# Is there another location Rails is looking for my irbrc config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb

I have my .irbrc located in my ~/.irbrc.

I noticed that when I run 'rails console' on a Rails 3.x application, it says that its looking for a gem.

```
Gems missing: no such file to load -- ap
```

but if I run just 'irb' or 'script/console' on a rails 2.x app, everything works as it should be.

Is there another location Rails 3 looks for irbrc config?

I'm not sure if this information is applicable, but I'm running RVM on my box (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just figured it out. I thought I paste it here for others who had the same problem as well.

According to http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/9/19/rails-3-bash-aliases-and-irbrc-configs/page/2

You'll need to add your system gems into the Gemfile for Rails 3 applications (Bundler issue).

I did the above and it works.

**Update**

It seems like https://gist.github.com/2643079 is the most elegant solution I've found so far. It works pretty well too.

Comment: feel free to award yourself the correct answer if that's what solved the problem.

Comment: While adding your development gems to the Gemfile gets around the problem, it is no good if you're working as part of a team using different environments. They should not be forced to use your dev gems and, in some cases (especially on windows), they may not work and can cause errors when trying to install gems. If you're working on this by yourself, or you all use the same tools, then fine. But it is something you should be aware of.

Comment: @idlefingers How would you suggest doing to go about solving this in a team environment?

Comment: @david-c, As I said in my answer, there's no particularly graceful way to deal with this yet. The way I've gotten around it personally is to just unpack the couple of gems I use for development to a folder in my home dir, then require them using the full path. Look at the Github ticket I linked to for more suggestions. I guess the best option for you depends how many gems you're needing to require and what it is they do.

Comment: For the record: 'ap' refers to the Awesome Print gem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of bundler and the way is disables system gems. There's a bunch of suggested ways to deal with this, none of them perfect (see [this ticket](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues#issue/183) on bundler for some suggestions).

Comment: "This is because of bundler and the way is disables system gems". It's partially because of that, and partially because Rails piggybacks on IRB to provide its console while also using bundler to manage capturing the gems used by the Rails app so they act as a unit. Rails needs something that is more cohesive and less intrusive for those of us who write both Rails and non-Rails Ruby apps and use IRB a lot. This catches me periodically and I have to stop and think "what's going on?!"

Comment: @the-tin-man, I disagree. The problem OP is describing is purely because of bundler. That's why him adding his development gems to the Gemfile fixed it for him. The way rails console works is basically just to load up the rails env and fire up irb. This is the least intrusive way possible, and does not affect the way irb works - it just adds a bunch of stuff to it. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb#L33) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb) to see what it does.